# Could someone avoid legal responsibility by transferring crypto coins multiple times between wallets before making an illegal purchase?

Tags: liability, cryptocurrency

**Suppose the following scenario.** Someone creates two different crypto wallets without leaving an online trace that links their real identity back to the wallets in any feasible way. Then purchases some amount of cryptocurrency from a public crypto exchange organization with US Dollars and transfers the corresponding coins to one of their wallets. As a legal duty in most countries, the crypto exchange organization must make a private copy of the transaction (to later be provided to the legal authorities when asked). Thus, forming a permanent connection between the person and the crypto wallet that is used in the exchange from a legal-proof point of view. Suppose this person then moves the coins into their secondary wallet and buys illegal stuff with it. Blockchain technology makes a permanent record every time a transaction is made, right. Therefore, the coin that went to illegal stuff could easily be traced back to the first wallet, hence to the person. Could the person avoid legal responsibility in the act of buying illegal stuff by stating `I just bought some food from someone with the relevant coins and transferred the coins to their wallet. I'm not responsible for the acts that happened afterward` pretending that the wallet that is used in the illegal purchase does not belong to them (the secondary wallet)

Comment: Alternative question: "Is money laundering a reasonable and usable way to avoid being prosecuted for illegal activities?"

Comment: @Moo I think you are ignoring the fact that this 'I bought some food from someone' situation could easily be a true story as well. Then what, are we gonna put the blame on someone for buying something from someone else?

Comment: Not really, since its still money laundering, even though you are leaning heavily on deniability.  You are out right asking in your question whether something establishes deniability, while the underlying act being described is still illegal in pretty much every jurisdiction everywhere.  Also remember that the entire crypto chain will hang around for ever, and all it takes is one tiny slip or vulnerability in the software used to establish your identity throughout the chain.  Don't do illegal things.

Comment: @Moo I agree, I may have asked the question the wrong way. I just like intellectual discussions on ideas about challenging real-life situations. But the problem is, this attitude is not so progressive. 'don't trust crypto', 'don't do illegal things. It's your opinion and I respect that ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Im fine with trusting crypto, I just know its limitations - there are a lot of people currently using crypto for all sorts of unsavoury activities who, I think, are going to have a rude awakening at some point when it becomes evident that not only were their crypto activities not actually secure, but they weren't even anonymous.  As for "don't do illegal things not being "progressive", Im fine with that also - doing illegal things isn't the sort of acceptable "progressive" I really want in this world...

Comment: @Moo I don't think it is fair to respond to a question regarding a hypothesis back with a 'don't do illegal things' by assuming the questioner is somewhat trying to circumvent an illegal situation that they are in by seeking help online. I was just trying to understand how could justice be served righteously even in such challenging situations without violating the rights of all the parties. It's evident that we see things from quite different perspectives. That's ok too. I like civilized discussion anyway.

Comment: The difficulty in you being caught doesn't detract from the illegality or responsibility of the crime.

Comment: @RonBeyer I agree; to be specific, there is a crime asked in the question. But the problem is, the jurisdiction does not know if there is a crime or not. That's exactly what I'm asking. Could this ambiguity save the person from being charged with the crime or not -since they could also be innocent? -Please excuse me if the question was ambiguous (and feel free to fix it).

Comment: @kozmon if thats the question you want to ask, then you need to clean up the question actually asked so it corresponds more to your clarification in the comments, because right now it looks like you are asking what I think you are asking, and not what you apparently want to ask.  My first comment here is extremely pertinent.

Comment: @Moo I'm not sure if that's necessary, since I don't think that it's very hard to get the point of the question, unless if one is interested more in producing problems instead of solutions. As a usual SO user who is all about going right into solutions, I am very surprised by the nit-picky nature of this law community. Very interesting. Though, I'm still thankful to everyone who is trying to contribute one way or another.

Comment: I am voting to close as asking for specific legal advice.  But this is really asking for an advice on how to get away with committing a crime.  I don't think it would take a lot to rephrase in a way that makes it more hypothetical.  But such rephrasing has to happen.  This cannot be a site which hosts questions that may *even appear* to be an advice for would-be criminals.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is really asking whether a given strategy for getting away with breaking the law is likely to work, not what the law is.

Comment: The fact that law enforcement needs to find evidence to prove things is an element of basically _every_ prosecution.  Someone who shot someone could just as well claim that someone stole their gun, killed the victim, and then returned it.  This is why law enforcement generally gets multiple pieces of evidence.

Comment: @RyanM I just wanted to know how the process would go in such a circumstance and could someone get away with their criminal act even if the evidence points to them one way or another (the connection between two wallets). And I think there is a difference in the examples we represent. In your example, the person who owns the gun must present the evidence for the gun being stolen. But in my example, I think the prosecution has to provide evidence for the person owning both wallets. I think there is huge difference.

Comment: Depends. Will you be smearing  your hands, keyboard and computer with lemon juice?

Comment: In my situation, the prosecution also needs to provide evidence that the person owns the gun and that the gun was used to shoot the person.  Even then, that _might_ not be enough to convince a jury beyond a reasonable doubt, so they'd probably try to find more evidence (such as evidence they were in the area, had motive, etc.).  Heck, in your situation the prosecutors might not even bother proving the person owned the first wallet, since all they have to prove is that they owned the one used to make the illegal purchase.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I was assuming that there was no other evidence

Comment: Ultimately "is the jury going to believe a given story?" is very fact-specific and is going to depend heavily on the specific facts presented to the jury, their judgement of the witnesses' credibility, etc.

Comment: @RyanM Yes, thank you. That was an answer what I supposed I would get in the first place. Boy it was hard to get a proper answer, though the question was relatively simpler, I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could the person avoid legal responsibility in the act of buying illegal stuff

If they avoid being **caught**, surely they will avoid legal responsibility.

Will they avoid being caught? That's a question of crime planning, not a question of law.

Comment: How does this go in a practical situation. Do you really think that the judge or the jury or the system itself would let someone like that just get away -Is our system that idealist yet?

Comment: @kozmon crimes need to be proved beyond reasonable doubt. So it all boils down to whether the prosecution can do it. Can they? That's, again, a question of crime planning.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that it is ambiguous whether in a given situation the person is assumed to be 'caught' or 'not'.  The evidence clearly shows 2 transactions, one is known to be done by someone, and the other one is not known. The only connection between the known wallet and the unknown wallet is the imaginery trade between the known guy and the unknown guy. The trade could be a false information or not. They both could be the same guy or not. So, how do you identify the situation. Is the guy now 'caught' or 'not'? How would such a case result in a real, practical situation?

Comment: @kozmon on the face of it, that will not be sufficient evidence to prove guilt, so the guy will likely not be even charged. But the law enforcement could, in theory, dig deeper and find some extra clues proving that both guys are the same person. Whether they could, and _how_ is a technical question that I can't speculate about.

Comment: Thank you very much for the final clarification. I'll make this answer accepted in a few days if no better answer is given.

Answer (score 6):

### No

If you break the law you are legally responsible.

Can you make it more difficult for law enforcement to find and prosecute you? Of course, that's why bank robbers wear masks.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Crypto swapping and there are many services that are set up to do precisely this(for a %of the swap as commission):
https://darknetone.com/top-6-anonymous-crypto-exchanges-with-no-kyc/
https://news.bitcoin.com/5-of-the-best-crypto-swapping-services/

And no, it'll not allow you to avoid legal responsibility, just make it harder to get caught.